# Reading Text file with delimiter to sqlite using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMFEN.png)
**Above is my sample text file with ! as delimiter**

**I want the data Table to look this image below Sqlite**

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQYSh.png)
Please, how can i insert this data into sqlite in python here is my code

```
    with open('corp.fr') as f:
    mylist = [tuple(x.split('!')) for x in f]
    conn = sqlite3.connect("alignmentset.db")
    conn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS native_align")
    conn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foreign_align")
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE native_align (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nlang TEXT)")
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE foreign_align (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, flang TEXT)")
    conn.executemany("INSERT INTO native_align (nlang) VALUES (?)", (mylist))
    conn.executemany("INSERT INTO foreign_align (flang) VALUES (?)", (mylist))
    conn.commit()
```

please help

Comment: What are the SQL statements supposed to do? What are the tables `native_align` and `foreign_align` supposed to be? Into which table do you want to insert your original text? How is your code not working for you?

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: I have already asked you three questions. You need to address these and edit your question with the answers.

Comment: native_align table will get first data which is Matiyu 1 save it

Comment: foreign_align table will get second data  which is !Mattieu Chapitre 1. save it and so on

Comment: Why did you replace your textual example data by images? Images are useless. Please restore the old content. Please edit your question instead of adding information in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Reading Text file with delimiter ... I want the data to split into two SQLITE tables.

1. Read your Text file **`line`** by **`line`**

   ```
   for line in f:
       ...
   ```
2. Use a Condition to decide which `line` goes into which sqlite `table`.

   ```
   if line is 'Matiyu 1':
       ...
   elif line is '!Mattieu Chapitre 1':
       ...
   ```
3. Insert the actual `line` into the sqlite `table`
4. Repeat from **1.** until all lines from Text file read.